# How to resize separate items in TextView Android

Tags: android, fromhtml

My TextView is composed of Tile and Rating with different sizes applied on them. so far I have tried to make i tried to display it using fromHtml But I am facing an issue i.e. the second part of string that is rating moves to next line all i want both of them to be at same line or better to say rating text followed by title on same line.
code:

```
private void populateTitleView(TextView textView,String title,String rating){
    String ratingText = "";
    if(!rating.equals("")){
        try{
            rating = YooTextUtils.roundOffDecimal(rating,2);
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }

        ratingText = "<span size='12px'>"+rating+" &#9733;</span>";
    }
    String formatedTitle = "<span size='30px'><h1>"+title+"</h1>"+ratingText+"</span>";
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(formatedTitle, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
    } else {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(formatedTitle));
    }
}
```

**Desired Result:**
[image: Desired Image]

Comment: Note that H# are block elements, not inline. Have you looked into Spannable's ( https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans )? Might be overkill but another option if just html is not enough for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
textView.setMaxLines(1);
```

or in xml textView tag :

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SpannableStringBuilder and RelativeSizeSpan:

```
String title="";
String rating= "";
String text = title+" "+rating;

SpannableStringBuilder ssBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
RelativeSizeSpan bigSize = new RelativeSizeSpan(8.0f);  // try changing these values
RelativeSizeSpan midSize = new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f);

ssBuilder.setSpan(
            bigSize, // set big size span 
            text.indexOf(title), 
            text.indexOf(title) + String.valueOf(title).length(), 
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE 
    );
    ssBuilder.setSpan(
            midSize,   // set mid size span
            text.indexOf(rating), 
            text.indexOf(rating) + String.valueOf(rating).length(), 
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE 
    );

    textView.setText(ssBuilder);  // display the spannable to textview
```

Comment: its not static word as you can see it populating through mehtod

Comment: It's an example. You can add text to String at runtime